# JavaScript - Compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen many posts about how to compare two arrays in JavaScript and do something if you find a match.
I wanted to know how to write the opposite.
I have two arrays and I want to do something when I don't find a match.

```
var a = [1,2,3,5];
var b = [4,7,5,5];


for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
       if(b[j]===a[i]){
          //do something
       }
   }
 }

 //somehow return 4, 7
```

Basically, I would like to find the reverse of the above.  If I dont find a match I would like to perform an action.  Where would my else statement go?

```
   loop1:                                                                                          
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){                                                                                                                        
            loop2:                                                                                        
            for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++){                                                                         
                if(b[j]==a[i]){                                          
                    console.log("break loop");                                                            
                    break loop2;                                                                          
                }                                                                                         
                else{                                                                                     
                    continue loop1;                                                                              
                }                                                                                         
            }                                                                                             
        }
```

This is as far as I've gotten, am I on the right track?

Comment: How do you get `[5, 7]` out of `[1, 2, 3, 5]` and `[4, 7, 5, 5]`?

Comment: Write a nested loop where you iterate the two arrays. Update a flag if a match is found.

Comment: minitech - my mistake I meant to only return 4 & 7 - updated the main post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to check if the value of any element of array **`a[]`** exists in array **`b[]`**, and you want to "do something" on the condition that there is "no match".

There are many different ways you can consider a "no match" condition.

In your first example that "does something" each time it finds a match, it will examine the value of each element of **`a[]`**, and compare that value to all elements of **`b[]`**, one by one. So, this compare proceedure is not dependent on the position of a match. Also, if the value of a particular element in **`a[]`** exists in multiple places within **`b[]`**, or if the value of a particular element in **`b[]`** exists in multiple places within **`a[]`**, then the code will "do something" for each of the multiple matches of the same element.

So, in the case of the sample data you provided:

```
var a = [1,2,3,5];
var b = [4,7,5,5];
```

the code will "do something" when it finds the "4th" element of **`a[]`** matches the "3rd" element of **`b[]`**, and it will "do something" again, when it finds the "4th" element of **`a[]`** matches the "4th" element of **`b[]`**. I assume that's how you wanted it, but if you only wanted to "do something" one-time if an element in **`a[]`** is found in one "or more" places within **`b[]`**, then you would only need to add a "break;" statement, immediately following the "do something" statement(s).

So, for your question, you said that instead, you want the "opposite": to "do something" when you don't find a match.

Taking that literally, you would just change the statement: **`"if(b[j]===a[i])"`**, to: **`"if(b[j] != a[i])"`**. Now, this is probably **not** what you want, because the "no match" condition would likely happen far too often:

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(b[j] != a[i]){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility, is that you want to "do something" if the value of an element of **`a[]`** can't be found anywhere in **`b[]`**. For this, you would examine the value of each element of **`a[]`**, and compare that value to all elements of **`b[]`**, one by one, and if after checking the value of all elements in **`b[]`** you couldn't find a match to the value of the current element of **`a[]`**, ***then*** you would "do something".

In this case, if you found a match of the current value from **`a[]`**, in **`b[]`**, further checking of that element of **`a[]`** would not be necessary. You would want skip the rest, and begin checking the next element of **`a[]`** to the elements of **`b[]`**. For this, you would want to use **`"continue outerloop;"`**.

```
outerloop:
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(b[j] === a[i]){
            continue outerloop;
        }
    }
    // if we get to here, then no value
    // of b[] matched the a[] value, so:
    // "do something"
}
```

A 3rd possibility, is that you want to "do something", only one time, if ***any*** element of **`a[]`** can't be found anywhere in **`b[]`**. For this, you would examine the value of each element of **`a[]`**, and compare that value to all elements of **`b[]`**, one by one, and if after checking the value of all elements in **`b[]`** you couldn't find a match to the value of the current element of **`a[]`**, you set a "flag" and exit all the loops using **`"break outerloop;"`**. Then at the end, if the flag is "set", you can "do something".

```
bflag=false;
outerloop:
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(b[j] === a[i]){
            continue outerloop;
        }
    }
    // if we get to here, then no value
    // of b[] matched the a[] value, so, 
    // set the flag (bflag)
    bflag=true;
    break outerloop:
}

if(bflag){
    // "do something"
}
```

If this code was called as a function, it could be simplified a bit:

```
outerloop:
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(b[j] === a[i]){
            continue outerloop;
        }
    }
    // if we get to here, then no value of b[] matched 
    // the a[] value, so, do-something and return "failed":
    // "do something"
    return false;
}

// all elements of a[] were matched to 
// elements of b[], so: return "success"
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - My scenario was specifically the third and this helped greatly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you got `[5, 7]` out of `[1, 2, 3, 5]` and `[4, 7, 5, 5]`, but you can compare two arrays using the [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
    return !a.some(function (e, i) {
        return e != b[i];
    });
}
```

This returns `true` if the two arrays are identical, otherwise you get a `false`.

So `compareArrays([1,2,3], [1,2,3])` would return `true`, while `compareArrays([1,2,3, 5], [4,5,7,7])` would return `false`

Comment: What about `compareArrays([1,2,3,5], [5,3,2,1])` does the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method still work???

Comment: @Chef_Code I tried it out and it doesn't work it. Even I was looking for something that does the same job as you require.

Answer (score 1):

you have somewhat near to the answer in your code. plz find code below:

```
var a = [1,2,3,5];
var b = [4,7,5,5];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    var bl = false;
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++)
    {
        if(a[i] == b[j])
        {
            bl = true;
        }
     }

    if(bl)
        alert("find match for : " + a[i]);
}
```

try this FIDDLE too http://jsfiddle.net/Ce7HB/2/

Answer (score 1):

### Misunderstood the question. This answers how to execute something when no intersection between two arrays was found.

> If I dont find a match I would like to perform an action.

The easiest thing would be using a helper function:

```
function findEqual(a, b) {
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)
      if(b[j]===a[i])
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

```
if (!findEqual(a, b)) {
  // do something
}
```

> Where would my else statement go?

You cannot really use an else statement here. If you don't want to use a helper function, you'd need to go with a boolean variable that stores whether the loop found a match, then test for that. @Bhavesh's answer has an example for that (although it doesn't exit the loops early).

However, there's a more interesting control structure: [labelled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

```
foundNothing: {
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)
      if(b[j]===a[i])
        break foundNothing;
  // else we're still here when the block was not "broken"
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I dont find a match I would like to perform an action.

The easiest thing would be using a helper function. Fortunately, [such](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) already exists for finding items in an array:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) // not found
        // do something
```

> Where would my else statement go?

You cannot really use an else statement here. If you don't want to use a helper function, you'd need to go with a boolean variable that stores whether the loop found a match, then test for that. @Bhavesh's answer has an example for that (although it doesn't exit the loops early).

However, there's a more interesting control structure: [labelled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    foundNothing: {
        for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            if(b[j]===a[i])
                break foundNothing;
         // else we're still here when the block was not "broken"
         // do something
    }
```

However, we can formulate that much easier by using the `continue` statement for a certain loop. If we found a particular item, we just go to the next item - if we didn't went away we haven't found anything.

```
tofind: for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)
        if(b[j]===a[i])
             continue tofind;
    // else we're still here
    // do something
}
```